# AsyncResult class not getting in callback function

Tags: asynchronous, delegates

here my code-

```
DateTimeDelegate dtdel = new DateTimeDelegate(GetCurrentDateTimeAt);
IAsyncResult async = dtdel.BeginInvoke(UserContext.Latitude.ToString(), UserContext.Longitude.ToString(), new AsyncCallback(DateTimeCallBack), null);
```

...

```
public DateTimeCallBack(IAsyncResult asy)
    {
        AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)asy; // error 'AsyncResult' could not be found

    }
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.aspx) class is defined in the `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging` namespace. Make sure you have included it. You may also checkout the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) on MSDN.